# Re-using mappings in automapper

Tags: automapper

My existing solution has a lot of repetition like so:

```
config.CreateMap<IPublishedContent, ContactListingPage>()
            .ForMember(n => n.Title, map => map.ResolveUsing(AppearanceManager.GetTitle));
config.CreateMap<IPublishedContent, NewsListingPage>()
            .ForMember(n => n.Title, map => map.ResolveUsing(AppearanceManager.GetTitle));
```

Is there a way to remove this repetition?
**I tried:** using an interface:

```
config.CreateMap<IPublishedContent, IHaveTitle>()
            .ForMember(n => n.Title, map => map.ResolveUsing(AppearanceManager.GetTitle));
```

But the actual map operations need to be to the concrete types, so this mapping is not used.

Note: I'm hoping to mix and match the mappings, so all pages have titles, and some pages have promotions, etc...

**I tried:**
Creating a custom type for title with implicit conversions to string, I think this 'would' work except for the fact that I actually need the `IPublishedContent` object as the input into the GetTitle method rather than the sub property `PublishedProperty` which it would  be mapped from.

Comment: You could use Generics helpers.

Comment: @aron I'm not sure what you mean, I couldn't find anything that might be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoMapper doesn't try to reuse mappings by design - mostly because I would confuse myself in these cases. You opt in to shared mappings:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<IPublishedContent, IHaveTitle>()
        .ForMember(n => n.Title, map => map.ResolveUsing(AppearanceManager.GetTitle));

    cfg.CreateMap<IPublishedContent, ContactListingPage>()
        .IncludeBase<IPublishedContent, IHaveTitle>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IPublishedContent, NewsListingPage>()
        .IncludeBase<IPublishedContent, IHaveTitle>();
});
```

I'm usually pretty careful about these because I don't necessarily want to introduce coupling on the ViewModel side. I've already removed the duplication through a shared resolver.

Comment: The example won't save much duplication in this case, but it could in more complicated mappings. Thanks for the answer, it's good to know it's by design :-) .... I think I could use reflection to find the objects with IHaveTitle interface and wire them all up